# list indices must be integers or slices, not str in my program

Tags: python, nltk, typeerror

I need this bit of code to work, code is probably from older versions of python and is causing problems in collab in the current day and giving me a type error:list indices must be integers or slices, not str, .What do i do to make this one runnable in the current version of collab?

```
for intent in intents['intents']: 
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(w)
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])
```

Comment: is `intents` a dictionary with `'intents'` as a key? Could you maybe give an example value for `intents`?

Comment: data_file = open('JEOPARDY_QUESTIONS1.json').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)
intents is the json.loads(data file)

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print(json.dumps(intents, indent=2))` ? (if its large reduce it down so you can provide us a good example of what the data structure looks like)

Comment: {
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greeting",
      "patterns": [
        "Hi there",
        "How are you",
        "Is anyone there?",
        "Hey",
        "Hola",
        "Hello",
        "Good day",
        "Hi"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Hello, thanks for asking",
        "Good to see you again",
        "Hi there, how can I help?",
        "Hello"
      ],
      "context": [
        ""
      ]
    }

Comment: kind of like this

Comment: wait i worked it out thanks a lot the prior json had a bit different structure i resolved it thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can add how you fixed it if you like.  It would help future users who come to the site.

Comment: I checked the structure of the .json file like was told to me and found that the given .json i was trying to use was different in structure and was not responding to the defined 'intents' so i downloaded a proper version ( old one was damaged ) of the .json file and it worked, kinda new to working with .json.